# Are chakra's used in Buddhism?

Tags: philosophy, terminology

I think that in the hindoestic yogi there are using chakra's very common. But are they also used in buddhism? If not, why not? Or what is similar to chakra's in buddhism?

Comment: see also, [Are the Chakras present in the original Buddha's teachings?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/are-the-chakras-present-in-the-original-buddhas-teachings)

Answer (score 1):

> But are they also used in buddhism?

There are some references to chakra in certain types of Buddhism. E.g. see [Are the Chakras present in the original Buddha's teachings?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2338)

> Or what is similar to chakra's in buddhism?

In Theravada Buddhism the closest is the places to fix attention or resting places of attention. See my answer to: [Are the Chakras present in the original Buddha's teachings?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/2402/295)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in say that in the Hindu Meditation practices the Chakra is used. Especially in types of Yoga practice such as ‘Lama Yoga’ they get you to energize your chakras, and fire up the kundalini using a type of breathing exercise. They refer to kundalini as a very transforming flame of raw sexual energy, and energizing the chakras is done by breathing exercises that requires excellent physical and cardiovascular health.

To me Buddhism is Theravada Buddhism, and there is absolutely no mention in the Doctrine of the use of chakras.  In fact the only place that I came of a mention of a chakra is regarding Supreme Buddha’s chief disciple, Moggallana. The other chief disciple was Ven. Sariputta who died half a year before the Final Passing Away of the Awakened One.

Soon after the death of Sariputta, Mara, the embodiment of evil and the Lord of Death, claimed Moggallana's mortal frame, by entering his bowels. He could not make him possessed by entering his head, because he had access only to the lowest Chakra. Moggallana, however, told him calmly to get out and away as he had well recognized him. Mara was very surprised that he had been found out so soon, and in his delusion he thought that even the Buddha would not have recognized him so quickly. But Moggallana read his thoughts and ordered him again to get away. So this is the only place that I found any mention of this.

Concentrating and calming the mind by breathing in and breathing out, mindfully with full awareness, is known as Anapanasati.   How mindfulness of in and out breathing brings the contemplation of body and contemplation of feeling to their culmination is explained very differently in the Buddhist Doctrine. In reading Ananda Sutta, Girimananda Sutta, Anapanasati Sutta etc. it will be obvious that this meditation needs to be developed and pursued ardently with thorough understanding and awareness as per the scriptures. At the same time be aware not to mix it that of Hindu meditation practices. Hindus advice you to first be aware of breathing by first fixing attention on the feeling of the breath at the nose palate (roof of the mouth) and then progress to places like the one located either in the middle of the chest or the solar plexus.

Comment: Buddha did not devise breath watching as it is a common practise amongst yogis. Infact Shiv who is considered first yogi and author of Bhairav Tantra has listed breath watching in his 108 meditation techniques. There is nothing Hinduism in it nor buddhism as Buddha learnt it from yogis/brahmans. Trivial details like watching breath on tip of the nose to solar plexus is not important. What is important is concentration power which along with breath watching is a potent method of mediation. If you watch breath with high concentration over a long period of time it slows down breathing to zero.

Comment: Shashank Khare what are you even talking about

Answer (score 0):

The Chakras corresponds to major energy exchange points between metaphysical and physical body. There are many exchange points other than seven major. Accupuncture talks about 600 plus points. Tantra Buddhism followed in Tibet talks about four chakras. Buddha remained silent because these Chakras are associated with psychic powers which are distractions in disciple path.
Best answer can be obtained by asking a living Buddha.

Answer (score 0):

The Tibetans have a chakra system similar to the Hindu system, but based on four, five, seven or even ten chakras instead of the familiar seven. The specific symbols of the individual chakras also differ somewhat, and the Hindu concept of kundalini is replaced by the notion of "airs" or "drops." The 32 marks of the Buddha also seem to include some nascent references to the chakras, especially the 1000-spoke wheel sign on the feet, golden-hued body, ten-foot aura, long and broad tongue, the white urna curl that emits light between the eyebrows, and the protuberance at the crown of the head.